# Why the DAO hacker could single handedly crash the ETC market many times over?

Tags: the-dao, attacks, hardforks, ethereum-classic

Disclosure: I started to read about crypto-coins a couple days ago.

I read in this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4ukefq/attacker_has_withdrawn_all_etc_from_darkdao_on/) comments that the DAO hacker, who holds many ETC (non-forked chain), can crash the market for good and end ETC life.  Is that a real possibility (ETC disappearing after a big sell-off) ?

EDIT : To be more specific : how a major sell-off can end a crypto-currency life ?

Comment: Welcome to the community!  This question is too close to several off-topic [areas](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  It might be worth discussing in [meta](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-topics-can-i-ask-about) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the DAO attacker could crash ETC by dumping his 3 million ETH might be an exaggeration. If analyzed using market economics, it acts more like a zero sum game, in that when someone sells, another person buys. The worst that could happen is that the attacker dumps the price which would let a few lucky people buy cheap ETC. As long as there is R&D happening and the platform is growing, then people will buy in. ETC more or less has ETH working for them for free, since everything can be cloned from ETH, so as long as ETH grows, ETC should be able to grow too within its niche.